# Using CURL to PUT JSON

Tags: json, curl

Working on a LinoVision POE camera and according to the API there is a way to control it by sending a JSON request. Can this be done using CURL or a straight up HTTP URL?

**Example JSON from the Manual:**

The format of common request is like

```
PUT /LAPI/V1.0/System/Time/NTP HTTP/1.1
{
"Enabled":1,
"AddressType":0,
"Address":"24.56.178.140",
"Port":123,
"SynchronizeInterval":60
}
```

When method is PUT/POST, HTTP Body usually needs to include JSON Data.
Request must be sent to the HTTP/HTTPS port of the device.

**PTZCtrl**

/LAPI/V1.0/Channels//PTZ/PTZCtrl

| URL | /LAPI/V1.0/Channels//PTZ/PTZCtrl |
| Description  | It is used control PTZ of the specified channel.    |
| Method  | PUT    |
| Input Data | PTZCommandInfo    |
| Success Return Data  | None    |

This is the actual PTZ information provided:

**PTZCommandInfo**

Json Block
{
"PTZCmd":,
"Para1":,
"Para2":,
"Para3":
}

| Param | Requirement | Type | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PTZCmd | M | unsigned long | PTZ operation command word: | 1794（0x0702） |
|  |  |  | 0x0101: Stop decreasing iris |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0102: Decrease iris |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0103: Stop increasing iris |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0104: Increase iris |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0201: Stop focusing near |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0202: Focus near |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0203: Stop focusing far |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0204: Focus far |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0301: Stop zooming in |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0302: Zoom in |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0303: Stop zooming out |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0304: Zoom out |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0402: Turn up |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0404: Turn down |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0502: Turn right |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0504: Turn left |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0702: Turn upper left |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0704: Turn lower left |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0802: Turn upper right |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0804: Turn lower right |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0901: Stop |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0A01: Wiper on |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0A02: Wiper off |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0B01: Light on |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0B02: Light off |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0C01: Heater on |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0C02: Heater off |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0D01: IR on |  |
|  |  |  | 0x0D02: IR off |  |

These are the HTTP URLs that I have tried to activate the LED light, but didn't work

```
http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl?Data={"PTZCmd":"1"}
http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl?Data={"PTZCmd":"0x0B01"}
```

Using HTTP URL I get this response:

```
{
"Response": {
    "ResponseURL": "/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl",
    "CreatedID": -1, 
    "ResponseCode": 0,
    "SubResponseCode": 0,
    "ResponseString": "Succeed",
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusString": "Succeed",
    "Data": {
    "PTZCmd":   0,
    "ContinueTime": 0,
    "Para1":    0,
    "Para2":    0,
    "Para3":    0
}
    }
}
```

These are the CURL command strings I have tried:

```
curl -d '{"PTZCmd":"0x0B01"}' -X PUT http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl
curl -d '{"PTZCmd":1}' -X PUT http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl
```

Neither option activates the light, but they both respond with this:

```
{
"Response": {
        "ResponseURL": "/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl",
        "CreatedID": -1,
        "ResponseCode": 0,
        "SubResponseCode": 0,
        "ResponseString": "Succeed",
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusString": "Succeed",
        "Data": "null"
        }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Using INT instead of Hex value doesn't activate light either.

```
curl -d '{"PTZCmd":2817}' -X PUT http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl
{
"Response": {
        "ResponseURL": "/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl",
        "CreatedID": -1,
        "ResponseCode": 0,
        "SubResponseCode": 0,
        "ResponseString": "Succeed",
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusString": "Succeed",
        "Data": "null"
        }
}
```

Comment: Try `curl -d '{"PTZCmd": 2817}' ...`. From the example column, `PTZCmd` appears to be an int

Comment: Tried using an INT instead of Hex, but LED still doesn't activate. Updated OP with new info.

Comment: I'd try the basic move commands first since those should always be supported, while the LED feature may or may not be accessible via the API. Also, I have the same API on my cam, where did you find the API commands documented like that?!

Answer (score 0):

@partofthething that is what I ended up doing in order to confirm the URL commands were correct. Great minds :-)

Anyway, this project was shelved after a bit of back and forth with the manufacturer. They do support manual control of the LED light, but only if the camera is set to "night mode". Unfortunately, for us anyway, night mode is grey scale only and we need to see color to determine the type of algae growth.

For posterity, these are the commands & URLS that work in the event some other person gets this camera:

##### Image snapshot=

```
http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/Media/Video/Streams/0/Snapshot
```

##### Change the timezone

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"TimeZone":"GMT-10:00"}' -g --anyauth -u 'username:password' -X PUT http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/System/Time
```

##### Activate LED light

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"PTZCmd":2817}' -g --anyauth -u 'username:password' -X PUT http://172.16.5.91/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/PTZ/PTZCtrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a URL to specify substream or resolution?

This URL works for Advidia M Series
http://cameraIP/LAPI/V1.0/Channels/0/Media/Video/Streams/0/Snapshot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).